# Converting React webpage to pdf with Pandoc

Tags: reactjs, pdf, html, pandoc

I made myself resume webpage with React. I want to make automated script that will convert that resume into PDF and I tried using Pandoc. I tried:

```
pandoc http://localhost:3000/ -o resume.pdf
```

Problem is that webpage is using Javascript to render itself and Pandoc doesn't run Javascript while converting. How can I make it work?

Comment: render your [react to static HTML first](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#pre-rendering-into-static-html-files).

Comment: This doesn't help since I need Javascript to fetch data. I might migrate to React Native with PDF renderer.

Comment: Then you'll have to do server-side-rendering with Node.js or try with `pandoc --pdf-engine=wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: It still doesn't enable javascript. It seems like I will just drop automated script and just convert to PDF manually.

Comment: It seems that there is problem with wkhtmltopdf in Arch Linux binaries. This could be a solution.